# By increasing the size of the piezoelectric ceramic disc used in ultrasonic humidifier, does it increase the amount of mist generated?

Tags: piezoelectricity

I'm fairly new to piezoelectricity and I have managed to research online on how ultrasonic humidifiers work. However, there has been very little mention on the size of the piezoelectric ceramic disc affecting the generation of mist. Will the amount of mist generated be the same or will it be different considering that only the size of the ceramic disc is changed?

Comment: size and power both matters

Answer (score 2):

Note that "large volume" mist generators don't have large disks.  Instead they use multiple disks.

Note that mist-generators use ~1MHz ultrasound, while ultrasonic cleaners with 3in disks at 30KHz only create droplets and no mist.  PROBABLY the disk size/frequency is important, and a large disk will give low frequency resonance, and different water interaction, and only create droplets or fine spray.

At work we use Lithium Niobate piezos above 10MHz generating micron-scale (invisible) droplets for mass-spectrometer sample input.  Much higher freq, much smaller mist.  Here's [various videos of surface-wave nebulizers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL87F690A21F36FEB3), producing audio at radio-freqs.    Higher frequency gives smaller ripples on water, which then spit out smaller droplets (like "chop" in ocean waves.)

Answer (score 1):

It would be reasonable to assume that a larger moving surface area could generate more mist than a smaller area. However it is also reasonable to assume that a larger piezo will require more power and probably a different frequency to maximize the effect.  And adjusting the amount of fluid allowed onto the surface would also optimize the action.